Existence of gap when the first energy level has an infinite degeneracy
Consider a Hamiltonian $H_N$ on a finite system with the following properties:

It has a unique ground state
The first excited energy level has a degeneracy $N$ (there are $N$ eigenstates for the first excited eigenvalue).

The question I have is the following:
Is it possible for such a hamiltonian to still have a spectral gap as we take the thermodynamic limit ($N\rightarrow \infty$).
My personal intuition was that the gap has to lift the eigenstates on the first energy level, so as the amount of eigenstates on the first level increases, the gap becomes smaller due to the weight.
However, this is of course just a very intuitive picture. Any explanations, counterexamples or references are very welcome.

I don't really understand the question. To put what you said in formula language, you have a system with a Hamiltonian $\hat{H} = \epsilon\sum_1^N|n\rangle \langle n| + \epsilon_0 |0\rangle \langle 0|$, where $\epsilon \neq \epsilon_0$. So what is the problem in just sending $N \rightarrow \infty$ ? In this light, the apparent answer is yes, the gap $\Delta = \epsilon-\epsilon_0$ remains.

A simple example of this is to consider $N$ spin 1/2 in a magnetic field (field along the $x$ direction):
$$
H = -B\sum X_i
$$
In this case, the gap is $2|B|$, the ground state being non degenerate and the first excited level being $N$ fold degenerate. More generally, you have $N+1$ levels $E_k = -|B|(N-2k)$ and degeneracy $\binom{N}{k}$. Thus, even in the thermodynamic limit, you maintain a band gap.
What is true though is that in the thermodynamic limit, you are also interested in extensive energy $\epsilon = E/N$. The entropy of the extensive energy does converge to a continuous function supported on $\epsilon\in(-|B|,|B|)$, so in this sense you do not see a gap in the density of states.
You can also notice that the gap is fairly robust. For example, if you add Ising like interactions:
$$
H = -B\sum X_i-J\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle}Z_iZ_j
$$
the $N$ fold degeneracy is lifted. At small $J$, you will instead get a small band of width proportional to $J$, so the gap persists.

Thanks a lot for your answer, but is it true then that in general the extensive energy is never gapped in our case?

You will need an extensive gap ($\propto N$) and an exponential degeneracy ($\asymp e^N$) to see the gap in the entropy

Would you know of any references where this topic is discussed?

Is there a reference for the last part where you mentioned that for an extensive gap an exponential degeneracy would be needed. I am not too familar with that result

It's just a naive scaling argument. The degeneracy scales as $W\asymp e^{Ns(E/N)}$ in the thermodynamic limit
